# Как организовать обратный SSH-туннель для стороннего пользователя?

Tags: сеть, ssh, linux

Дано:

1. Машина А во внутренней сети с ip: 192.168.1.100, на ней есть сервис на порту 5555
2. Пограничный сервер Б, который имеет доступ в локалку 192.168.1.x и наружу в инет (белый ip - a.b.c.d).

Хочу:

1. Дать доступ к порту 5555 на машине А любому пользователю интернета, через обратный ssh туннель через машину Б

Делаю:

- На машине А.

> ssh -R 44444:192.168.1.100:5555 user@machine_b

- На машине B

  ```
  bash-3.2$ netstat -anp| grep 44444
  tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44444              0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      -
  tcp        0      0 ::1:44444                    :::*            LISTEN      -
  ```

слушается только локальный интерфейс, снаружи попасть на 44444 порт нельзя. Что сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вопрос решён.

1. `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` → `GatewayPorts = yes`
2. `ssh -R \*:44444:192.168.1.100:5555 user@machine_b`