# Как пробросить порт на ПК используя VPS?

Tags: linux, windows, сервер

Как можно пробросить (открыть) порт на нескольких ПК на винде без установки каких либо драйверов и прочего используя VPS на линуксе, что-то вроде ngrok.io, но своими руками.

Comment: вам нужен ssh port forwarding

Comment: если @etki понял вопрос верно (вероятно, он в курсе, что это за загадочный «вроде ngrok.io»), то вот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/311412/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin https://ngrok.com